# How to configure import preferences and exclusions in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, import, visual-studio-code

- I would like to disable import suggestions from a `dist` folder.
- <s>I would like to only use **relative** imports.</s>

I tried setting

- <s>`"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"`</s>
  *After importing, the path is indeed relative. Also works with `shortest`.*
- `files.exclude`
- `files.watcherExclude` (not even restart helps)
- `search.exclude`
- tsconfig.json - `exclude: ['dist']`

*note: All extensions are disabled*
[image: 1]

*Note that the folder disappears from project, but it is still suggested.*
*BTW, I **do want** to keep the folder **visible** in project.*
[image: 2]

Comment: Are any of the files under `src` referencing `dist` directly? This could cause the `dist` files to be pulled into your project

Comment: @MattBierner Nope, no file from `dist` is referenced anywhere. I even tried deleting the folder altogether. No error raised.